# React Router + Redux - Dispatch an async action on route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a universal react app that's using redux and react-router.

I have several routes as follows:

```
/2016
/2015
/2014
/2013
```

etc.

Each route requires data from an API. Currently, i have the `<Link>` elements in the Navigation component dispatch an async action `onClick`, which populates the store with data from the API for that route.

For MVP, i'm just overwriting the `post: {}` contents in the store with the new post contents when the route changes, that way we get any new content that was on the API.

I've realise that having the action dispatchers on the `<Link>` buttons isn't optimal, as hitting the back button does not re-trigger the action dispatch to get the content for the previous route.

Is there a way to get React Router to trigger the dispatch action anytime a route change occurs? (Limiting it to listen to a specific set of routes would be a bonus).

*I realise i should be getting the history from the store, but for now, it's easier to hit the API again by triggering an action dispatch **in order to get the new content**.*

Cheers.

Comment: In addition to Matthew Barbara, we can use store.dispatch for dispatching any actions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 'lifecycle' hook `onEnter` and `onChange` has been removed in React-router 4 which makes most of the other answers to this question out-dated.

Whilst I recommend you to use your components **lifecycle methods** to achieve your goal, here is an answer to your question which works on React-router 4.

What works today is listen to the history change using [History library](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) created by the developers of React router themself and dispatch async actions from there.

```
// history.js
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"

const history = createHistory()

// Get the current location.
const location = history.location

// Listen for changes to the current location.
const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
    //Do your logic here and dispatch if needed
})

export default history
```

Then import the history in your application

```
// App.js
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import history from './history';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Source: [History library](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history)
[React router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)

Comment: How would you dispatch inside the history listener? I mean, how is `dispatch` available?

Comment: `action` is the history action. Just a string. In my case it's `"REPLACE"`

Answer (score 8):

Yeah React Router has onEnter and onLeave hooks. You could build your routes to take your `store` instance, so you can access it in those helpers:

```
const createRoutes = (store) => {
  const fetchPosts = () => store.dispatch({
    types: ['FETCH_POSTS', 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS', 'FETCH_POSTS_FAIL',
    url: '/posts'
  });

  return (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="posts" component={PostList} onEnter={fetchPosts}/>
      <Route path="posts/:id" component={PostDetail} />
    </Route>
  )
}
```

A better solution is to use something like [`redial`](https://github.com/markdalgleish/redial) or [`redux-async-connect`](https://github.com/Rezonans/redux-async-connect). This allows you to co-locate your component's data dependencies with your components, while retaining the ability to test your components without touching the network.

*Edit*: This applies to an old, no longer supported version of `react-router`.

Comment: Nice!! I couldn't get Redial to work (for some reason the hooks weren't firing, and the promise was resolving instantly), so i've implemented your example while i try and use an alternative. Works!

Comment: Is this undocumented or only for older versions of react-router? I couldn't find any mention of the `onEnter` and `onLeave` hooks in the documentation.

Comment: @HåkenLid unfortunately this is outdated. Posting an updated answer

Comment: You should edit this answer instead. Or at least add an explanation of which version of react router it applies to.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have actions dispatched from the render prop itself:

```
<Route to="path" render={ props => {
  this.props.toggleInfoLayer(true);
  return <UserInfo />;
}} />
```

This is assuming you are using Redux's `mapDispatchToProps` argument.

I tried using the history change event handler as mentioned in the accepted answer, but I found it undesirable to be dispatching actions from a rogue file. One more place I had to think about, when Redux already provides plenty too many.

Comment: I really like this answer, but unfortunately `react-dom` complains for me with a runtime warning in a development environment: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`