# Dispatch action on route change with BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I need to dispatch a Redux action every time there is a route change in my app. Unfortunately, [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406584/react-router-redux-dispatch-an-async-action-on-route-change) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109067/react-router-v4-dispatch-redux-action-on-page-change) don't apply to my case, since I have to use `BrowserRouter` instead `Router`, and `BrowserRouter` does not take a `history` prop. Is there another way to do this? I am using V4.

Comment: You could create a component and watch for changes in the props with [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md). When those props change fire off the event. What have you tried so far? Here's a basic approach. This assumes you can use hooks from redux. I'd recommend also upgrading your router if you can so you can use the hooks from that package as well. https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-knuth-oyz07

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dennis' comment gave a working solution, using React hooks. Make a new component as follows:

```
const RouteChange = withRouter(({ location }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "AN_ACTION" });
  }, [dispatch, location.pathname]);

  return null;
});
```

and just include it in the root of your application. The specified action will be dispatched whenever the route changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentwillunmount in each of your react class and it will work fine